# Making jCarousel work with view

Tags: 7, views, javascript

I am trying to make jCarousel work with Views in Drupal 7. I select the required fields and write in the footer part of the view like the following one:

```
 <?php 
  jcarousel_add('slideshow-item-list', array('auto' => 2,'visible' => 3));
 ?>
```

It is not working properly. The next and previous buttons do not show up. Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: do you have  alink to your test page? Double check that the css uses the right path to the images.

Comment: @tecjam - jcarousel module had a option for this and it worked fine.

Comment: Sorry, I don;t know the jcarousel module. I would have simply hard coded this into my theme rather than using modules. If the images do not show up, check where the error is using firebug in firefox. Checking that the images are called correctly via the css would be the first thing to do.